# iOS App crashes on startup without showing any errors

Tags: iphone, memory, crash

I understand that there are others that have this problem, and I have looked at a ton of posts with this problem but still can't figure out why my app keeps crashing. I just don't understand what is happening ='( I have tried cleaning everything out, commenting out parts of my code, and following the other answers to this problem but to no avail. Here is my viewControler.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

//txt fields for max value and thread
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtNumThreads;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtMaxValue;

//labels for time elapsed, primes found, and time
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTimeElapsed;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblPrimesFound;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTime;

//actions for each of the buttons
- (IBAction)btnStart_click:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnClear_click:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnTime_click:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnShow_click:(id)sender;

//show button and text view to show results
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnClear;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnShow;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnStart;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtViewResults;

//boolean to determine if the start button has been pressed once already
@property bool isComputing;

//for number of threads and max value
@property int NumThreads;
@property int MaxValue;
@property int sqRoot;

//array for primes and results
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *SieveArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *PrimesAndThreads;

@end
```

And this is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

//symbolic constants for max number of threads and max value
static const int MAX_NUM_THREADS = 4;
static const int MAX_VALUE = 9999;

@synthesize isComputing;
@synthesize sqRoot;
@synthesize NumThreads;
@synthesize MaxValue;
@synthesize SieveArray;
@synthesize PrimesAndThreads;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //to dismiss the keyboard using tap gesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    //add tap gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    //start with isComputing being false
    isComputing = false;

    //allocate
    SieveArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    PrimesAndThreads = [NSMutableArray array];
}

//to dismiss the keyboard using resign first responder
-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.txtMaxValue resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtNumThreads resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//click event for the start button
- (IBAction)btnStart_click:(id)sender {
    //clear contents of boxes
    self.txtViewResults.text = @"";

    if(SieveArray)
        [SieveArray removeAllObjects];

    if(PrimesAndThreads)
        [PrimesAndThreads removeAllObjects];

    [self.btnShow setEnabled:FALSE];

    if([self txtNumThreads].text.length != 0 && [self txtMaxValue].text.length != 0)
    {
        //get the user entered data
        NumThreads = [self.txtNumThreads.text intValue];
        MaxValue = [self.txtMaxValue.text intValue];

        if(NumThreads <= MAX_NUM_THREADS && MaxValue <= MAX_VALUE && NumThreads > 0)
        {
            //square root for the max number of divisions
            sqRoot = sqrt(MaxValue);

            //array for the algorithm
            for(int i = 0; i < MaxValue+1; i++)
                [SieveArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];


            switch (NumThreads) {
                case 1:
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:0 Right:MaxValue ThreadNum:1];
                    });
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    int FirstHalf = MaxValue/2;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:0 Right:FirstHalf ThreadNum:1];
                    });

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:FirstHalf+1 Right:MaxValue ThreadNum:2];
                    });
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    int OneThird = MaxValue/3;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:0 Right:OneThird ThreadNum:1];
                    });

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:OneThird+1 Right:OneThird*2 ThreadNum:2];
                    });

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:(OneThird*2)+1 Right:MaxValue ThreadNum:3];
                    });
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    int OneFourth = MaxValue/4;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:0 Right:OneFourth ThreadNum:1];
                    });

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:OneFourth+1 Right:OneFourth*2 ThreadNum:2];
                    });

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:(OneFourth*2)+1 Right:OneFourth*3 ThreadNum:3];
                    });

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
                        [self SieveAlgorithm:(OneFourth*3)+1 Right:MaxValue ThreadNum:4];
                    });
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *ExceedMaxError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please enter between 1 and %d threads, and a max of %d for value.", MAX_NUM_THREADS, MAX_VALUE] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [ExceedMaxError show];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *blankTextsError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enter No Threads and Max Value." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [blankTextsError show];
    }

    [self.btnShow setEnabled:TRUE];
}

//click event for the clear button
- (IBAction)btnClear_click:(id)sender {
    self.txtMaxValue.text = @"";
    self.txtNumThreads.text = @"";
    self.txtViewResults.text = @"";
}

//click event for the time button
- (IBAction)btnTime_click:(id)sender {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    self.lblTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:now]];
}

//click event for the show button
- (IBAction)btnShow_click:(id)sender {
    //clear the result text view
    self.txtViewResults.text = @"";

    for(id object in PrimesAndThreads)
    {
        self.txtViewResults.text = [self.txtViewResults.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", object]];
    }

    if(PrimesAndThreads)
        [PrimesAndThreads removeAllObjects];
}

//Sieve Algorithm function
//Takes the left and right subscript of the range and performs the algorithm on SieveArray
-(void)SieveAlgorithm:(int)left Right:(int)right ThreadNum:(int)thread {

    //get rid of multiples of i to square root of MaxValue
    for(int i = 2; i <= sqRoot; i++)
    {
        for(int x = i+i; x <= right; x=x+i)
        {
            [SieveArray replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        }
    }

    //add the primes to a string array for printing later
    for(int l = left; l <= right; l++)
    {
        if([[SieveArray objectAtIndex:l] integerValue] == 1)
            [PrimesAndThreads addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ThNum:%d Prime:%d", thread, l]];
    }
}
@end
```

Upon crashing I get taken to this:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x10e608c:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x10e6090:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x10e6094:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x10e6096:  je     0x10e60e8                 ; objc_msgSend + 92
0x10e6098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x10e609a:  pushl  %edi
0x10e609b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi
0x10e609e:  pushl  %esi
0x10e609f:  movl   (%edi), %esi
0x10e60a1:  movl   %ecx, %edx
0x10e60a3:  shrl   $2, %edx
0x10e60a6:  andl   %esi, %edx
0x10e60a8:  movl   8(%edi,%edx,4), %eax
0x10e60ac:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x10e60ae:  je     0x10e60b9                 ; objc_msgSend + 45
0x10e60b0:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx
0x10e60b2:  je     0x10e60d0                 ; objc_msgSend + 68
0x10e60b4:  addl   $1, %edx
0x10e60b7:  jmp    0x10e60a6                 ; objc_msgSend + 26
0x10e60b9:  popl   %esi
0x10e60ba:  popl   %edi
0x10e60bb:  movl   4(%esp), %edx
0x10e60bf:  movl   (%edx), %eax
0x10e60c1:  jmp    0x10e60d9                 ; objc_msgSend + 77
0x10e60c3:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)
0x10e60d0:  movl   8(%eax), %eax
0x10e60d3:  popl   %esi
0x10e60d4:  popl   %edi
0x10e60d5:  xorl   %edx, %edx
0x10e60d7:  jmpl   *%eax
0x10e60d9:  pushl  %eax
0x10e60da:  pushl  %ecx
0x10e60db:  pushl  %edx
0x10e60dc:  calll  0x10d3df3                 ; _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3
0x10e60e1:  addl   $12, %esp
0x10e60e4:  xorl   %edx, %edx
0x10e60e6:  jmpl   *%eax
0x10e60e8:  calll  0x10e60ed                 ; objc_msgSend + 97
0x10e60ed:  popl   %edx
0x10e60ee:  movl   1007235(%edx), %eax
0x10e60f4:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x10e60f6:  je     0x10e60fe                 ; objc_msgSend + 114
0x10e60f8:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x10e60fc:  jmp    0x10e6098                 ; objc_msgSend + 12
0x10e60fe:  movl   $0, %edx
0x10e6103:  ret
```

With this highlighted as the breakpoint:

```
0x10e60b2:  je     0x10e60d0                 ; objc_msgSend + 68
```

And this as the output:

```
(lldb)
```

I seriously haven't the first clue why it stopped working, it seemed like one minute it was working and then it stopped, but I also tried making it clean and reseting the simulator but that didn't do it..any help would be enormously appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you explain what happens when it crashes..?

Comment: Yup, added it in an edit just now.

Comment: the crash you are getting here is obj mes send. This only encounters when you are trying to use or utilise the object which is no more available in the memory.

Comment: try to enable nszombies for your project. It will give you exact problem for the crash why you are getting it.

Comment: @Abhishek that and whenever you simply send a message to an object that does not implement a selector for it. e.g. send `addObject:` to an instance of `NSString`.

Comment: This is crazy, I added NSZombies and now suddenly it runs! Can I leave that in there without any other effect?  Thank you by the way!!!

Comment: Thank you, but I had already posted it to stackoverflow and was told to post it here instead.

Comment: Also @Till I was wondering, is there a better way to pass this string to the array?  (I am failry new to ios dev).  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: but try to solve this as you can`t upload your app when nszoombies are enabled

Comment: Posting the stack trace from the crash report in the device logs would give us some more insight into the problem.

Comment: You should really get your coding style straight. Almost anything but class names should start with non-capital letters. Use boolean properties named without "is" and add a getter instead following that naming scheme; `@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isComputing) BOOL computing;`. I would also recommend using fully qualified properties using `self.`. Well, and there certainly is more to polish. However, none of the above will fix your issue, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

At a Glance.

```
SieveArray = [NSMutableArray array];
PrimesAndThreads = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Should be

```
SieveArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
PrimesAndThreads = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: This wont make a difference under ARC.

Comment: True however it's bad form.